# Update widget after sms receive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i'm having some trouble about this operation.
I have a widget that update some things. When arrive an sms , i wanna update it after receiving. I have written a BrodCastReceiver Class, but it update before arrive.

```
 public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
 {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            



        ComponentName name = new ComponentName(context, Randomnuberwidget.class);
        int [] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(name);


        Intent update = new Intent();
        update.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
        update.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        context.sendBroadcast(update);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add an if statement checking the action of the intent...  as far as i can tell a broadcastreciever is capable of picking up any implicit broadcast intent, so your code will fire anytime there is such a broadcast intent the way you have it set up now...

try adding

```
if (bundle.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"){
//update widget
}
```

grant i'm not certain about the if statement, but it should be a minor variation on that...